# eBay Trading API: Get all modified items in a time-range

Tags: ebay-api

We got an ebay-store. Our support staff adds items through the standard ebay-interface. When they do this to add a new item, I can get this item through the `GetSellerList`-call. But when they only change something in the text or modify the item in another way, the `GetSellerList`-call will fail to notify me about that. I need those modifications because we include our SKU in the article-text and this is something, our support will adjust. Had some one a similar problem and found a way to solve this?

Comment: Must it be Trading API? You can reach your goal by Finding API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can select all revised item and filter them.
Let me explain what i'm thinking about.
I would use the output selector to limit result of each call. i would only return intersting data such as itemID, SKU, (and what else you need toghter with two fields i'm talking about next). Then i would filter answer by using   `ItemArray.Item.ReviseStatus.ItemRevised`if is true than item have been revised previously so i would put in array.

from documentation

```
    If true, indicates the item was revised since the listing became active. 
    Output only.
```

I would definitely store all returned data in a table so i would be able to check for new entries / new revisions. 
When a new entry is found/updated you can do what ever you need, for example email yourself to know what items have been revised.

Field wich can give you revision details is `ItemArray.Item.ReviseStatus.ItemRevised`

from documentation:

```
    An output value only, indicates whether an item has been revised since the 
    listing became active and, if so, which among a subset of properties have 
    been changed by the revision.
```

I hope this can help.

Comment: So far, this is the only possible way I can imagine. Sadly.

Comment: I know... they should improve their filters though

Comment: You mean still using GetSellerList method? I have about 1500 active aucitons and I just can't fetch them all and filer... At least in PHP. Is this really only way to do this?

Comment: Yeah as far it seems so, you will need to loop throw the pages

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use [GetSellerEvents](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetSellerEvents.html#GetSellerEvents) instead of GetSellerList - there You can specify ModTimeFrom and ModTimeTo input properties

I will check how it works :)